# If the determinant of a coefficient matrix is 0, can you use inverse matrices to solve the system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

If the determinant of a coefficient matrix is 0, can you use inverse matrices to solve the system of equations? Explain your answer.

I believe the answer is no, because if our determinant is equal to 0 then we cannot have a inverse matrix since we cannot divide by 0.

Is this the correct answer or somewhat close?

Comment: That isn't a definitive proof; that just tells you that you can't use Cramer's rule.  You should look through your textbook and find what they say about determinants; there should be a point where they prove that a matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is non-zero.

Comment: I suppose you were technically correct about saying that the reason is that "we cannot divide by zeros".  That being said, the other details are important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.  If a matrix has a determinant of $0$, it can't have an inverse.

A proof of this is as follows: let $A$ be a matrix whose determinant is $0$, and suppose that $B$ were a matrix such that $AB = I$.  We know that
$$
1 = \det(I) = \det(AB) = \det(A)\cdot\det(B) = 0\cdot \det(B)
$$
That is, we would find that $B$ is a matrix whose determinant satisfies $0\cdot \det(B) = 1$.  Since zero times anything is zero, no such matrix $B$ can exist.

So, $A$ cannot have an inverse.

Note, however, that even if $A$ has a determinant of zero, the system $A x = b$ still might have a solution.  It just so happens that whenever an $A$ with determinant zero has a solution, it must have infinitely many other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your terms. If the equation of the linear system is

$$
A x = b \quad (*)
$$

and you call $A$ a coefficient matrix, $x$ a solution vector and $b$ a target vector (or whatever), then you need

$$
\det A \ne 0
$$

for $A^{-1}$ to exist, so you can not use such.

Why does $\det A = 0$ deny an inverse for $A$?

If the determinant vanishes, that means that the oriented paralellepiped volume formed by the $n$ column vectors of $A$ is degenerated, so they can not be linear independent. That in turn means that $\dim \mbox{rg} A < n$ and thus $\dim \mbox{ker} A > 0$ which denies a unique solution $x$, as all vectors from $x + \mbox{ker} A$ would solve $(*)$.

If a right-inverse matrix $B$ to $A$ would exist, we would have $A B = E$. And we would have $A B' = E$ too, where $B' = B + x_k \ne B$ is a matrix where some non-trivial $x_k \in \mbox{ker} A$ is added to one of the column vectors from $B$, yielding another, different right-inverse of $A$.

However a right-inverse of a matrix is a left-inverse as well:
$$
C A = E = A B \implies (C A) B = (AB) B \iff C (AB) = E B \iff C = B
$$
and it should be unique:
$$
A B' = E = A B \implies B (AB') = B(AB) \iff (BA)B' = (BA) B \iff B' = B
$$
which contradicts that we found a second one.

Note: user $\mbox{Om}(\mbox{nom})^3$ is right that even without existing $A^{-1}$ the equation $A x = b$ might hold and has a solution.

Example:
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
4 \\
2
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
6 \\
12
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have a linear system $Ax=b$ and $\det(A)=0$ you cannot get $b=A^{-1}x$ since $A^{-1}$ doesn't exists.

However you can use inverse matrices to solve the system after a careful study of it. Let me explain with an example. If $Ax=b$ and $\det(A)=0,$ assuming the system is compatible, it must be an indeterminate system. For example

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} x+y+z & = & 3 \\ x+y-z & = & 1 \\ 2x+2y & = & 4\end{array}\right.$$

is a compatible system with $\det(A)=0.$ This is due to the fact that the third equation is the sum of the other two. So the system is equivalent to

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} x+y+z & = & 3 \\ x+y-z & = & 1 \end{array}\right.$$ which is a compatible system, but indeterminate. We can write it as

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} y+z & = & 3-x \\ y-z & = & 1-x \end{array}\right.$$ or equivalently

$$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}y\\ z\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}3-x\\1-x\end{matrix}\right).$$ Now we can do

$$\left(\begin{matrix}y\\ z\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{matrix}\right)^{-1}\left(\begin{matrix}3-x\\1-x\end{matrix}\right)$$ to get

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} y & = & 2-x \\ z & = & 1 \end{array}\right.$$ and write the solution as a parametric line

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} x & = & \lambda, \\ y & = & 2-\lambda, \\ z & = & 1, \end{array}\right. \qquad \lambda\in\Bbb{R}.$$

Note that it doesn't work if we write

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} x+y & = & 3-z \\ x+y & = & 1+z \end{array}\right.$$

So, in general, if you have an indeterminate system ($\det A=0$) you have to look for the largest non-vanishing minor and proceed as in the example.